# Slide in from the right when popping a view controller from a navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios

Right now when I pop a custom view controller off the navigation controller stack (with animated:YES) it does the usual slide out to the right.  I want to have the animation look the same as when you push a controller (slide in from the right), but have the effect of still being a pop not a push.  How should I start my quest?  Should this be done in the viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once did a custom animation of a view, similar to this. As for getting started, I would look into [the core animation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). A better match than that, for what you want, to might be  [UIView animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) in the Apple Documentation.

Basically, you set the frame in `viewDidLoad` to be offscreen. Then in `viewDidAppear`, you set the frame to be the end frame, but wrap it in this code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationsNameThisCanBeAnythingOrNil" context:nil]
//Reset the frame here
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone, this is the code that I'm using to accomplish what was asked for:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
[[self.navigationController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

You might want to make sure that the underlying UIView that you are popping FROM has a clear background otherwise as you pop you'll see the old UIView fade to white as it slides away.